# Notice: Undefined index: songtitle. Get value from an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

So I decoded my json, and I get this array out of it

```
Array ( 
[totalstreams] => 1 
[activestreams] => 1 
[currentlisteners] => 0 
[peaklisteners] => 2 
[maxlisteners] => 100 
[uniquelisteners] => 0 
[averagetime] => 0
[version] => 2.4.0.147 (posix(linux x64))
[streams] => Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[id] => 1 
[currentlisteners] => 0 
[peaklisteners] => 2 
[maxlisteners] => 100 
[uniquelisteners] => 0 
[averagetime] => 0 
[servergenre] => Misc 
[serverurl] => http://example.com 
[servertitle] => Van Den Berg Stream 
[songtitle] => Katy Perry - This Is How We Do 
[streamhits] => 3 
[streamstatus] => 1 
[backupstatus] => 0 
[streampath] => /stream 
[streamuptime] => 1998 
[bitrate] => 128 
[content] => audio/mpeg ) ) )
```

I got to this using:
 `print_r($json)`

I'm interested in the `songtitle` part, so normally I'd go:

```
$json['streams']['songtitle'];
```

But it just throws a `Undedefined index error`.

Do you huys know what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json['streams'][0]['songtitle'];
```

That is what you want. Look carefully at your `print_r` results again, you'll notice the following after streams:

```
[streams] => Array ( [0] => Array (
```

You need to take that `0` into account.

Comment: Thanks man! I'll accept this one when the time limit let me :D